# Monad Transformers in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I have been trying simple Monad Transformers where I have for comprehensions involving `M[F[A]]` where `M` and `F` are monads. How can I make `M[F[A]]` and `M[S[A]]` work together in a for comp if `S` is a different monad?

For example:

```
val a: Future[List[Int]] = ...
val b: Future[Option[Int]] = ...
```

`a` requires a `ListT[Future, Int]` and `b` requires an `OptionT[Future, Int]` but these do not compose, do I need to use another transformer? Would this depend on the order I use them in the for comp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Monad Transformers help you in composing two values of type `F[G[X]]`.

In other terms, monad transformers work with `F[G[X]]` because they leverage the fact that you know how to compose two `G[X]` if `Monad[G]` exists.

Now, in case of `F[G[X]` and `F[H[X]]`, even if you state that `G` and `H` have `Monad` instances, you still don't have a general way of composing them.

I'm afraid composing `F[G[X]]` and `F[H[X]]` has no general solution with monad transformers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a monad transformer stack `ListT[OptionT[Future, Int]]` which combines all effects at once. You can lift `a` and `b` into values of that monad transformer stack.